# Imagining alternatives to the Cartesian coordinate system

Tags: geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

First, I should disclose that I am no mathematician, I am an architect and artist with a crush on geometry :) So please be lenient if my question is non-sense!

I'm interested in exploring the possibility of rewriting trigonometry and other functions in a tetrahedral coordinate system. I've been thinking about how the progression of dimensions from 0D to 3D could lead to the tetrahedron being a natural next step instead the cube inferred by the cartesian coordinate system, and how this could potentially simplify calculations and reveal new insights into mathematical concepts.

Starting from 0D, a point is defined by a single coordinate. Moving to 1D, a line is defined by two coordinates, and in 2D, a plane is defined by three coordinates. When we move to 3D, a cube is defined by eight coordinates, and we use a Cartesian coordinate system to represent these coordinates.

However, a the tetrahedron has four vertices and six planes, and would seem thus more "logical" or rigorous in the progression. The tetrahedron has several interesting properties, such as its symmetry and its ability to divide space into four equal volumes. Because of these properties, could the tetrahedron provide a more symmetrical representation of space than the cube, simplify certain calculations and make certain mathematical concepts easier to understand?

Therefore, I'm wondering if it is possible to rewrite trigonometry and other functions in a tetrahedral coordinate system, and how this could potentially be done. I'm also interested in any existing literature or resources on tetrahedral coordinates and their properties, and any potential challenges or drawbacks to using a tetrahedral coordinate system.

Thank you for your insights and suggestions!

Comment: Before using a tetrahedron to replace Cartesian coordinates in three-dimensional space, you might try using a triangle to replace Cartesian coordinates in a plane.

Comment: Such coordinate systems exist, lookup for example [barycentric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) coordinates, or [trilinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_coordinates) and [quadriplanar](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadriplanarCoordinates.html) coordinates. Don't know why you think trigonometry "*and other functions*" would need to be rewritten, though. Algebra is the same whether you write the numbers in base 10 or binary or roman numerals, for that matter.

Comment: By the way, a cube doesn't have any coordinates until you define a coordinate system. Perhaps you meant it has eight vertices? (The tetrahedron has only four.) Also, while you can fill all of three-dimensional space with cubes, you cannot fill three-dimensional space with tetrahedra; I don't get your remark about "four equal volumes."

Comment: The general idea behind this question is intriguing, however. As the sine and cosine functions relate to coordinates on the unit circle in a Cartesian coordinate plane, it might be interesting to see what functions relate to the coordinates of the circle in your coordinate system on a plane.

Comment: As indicated by David K and dxiv, consider first the question in 2D with a triangular grid (set of lines with resp. equations $y=p\sqrt{3},y=\sqrt{3}(x+q), y=-\sqrt{3}(x+r)$, $p,q,r \in \mathbb{Z}$) and the so important "barycentric coordinates" with respect to one of these triangles. Only in a second step, work with their close cousins, the "tetrahedral coordinates".

Comment: @DavidK thank you for your response! To answer your question, if you draw planes from the edges of the tetrahedron to its volume center, the polyhedron is subdivided into 4 identical pyramids, one for each face. And yes the fact that a tetrahedron does not tessellate space is intriguing, but it bears the question, would it in a non-Euclidean setting? Once again, sorry if this comes across as ignorant, I am so out of my depth! Cheers and thank you

Comment: @JeanMarie thank you, great starting point!

Comment: @dxiv thank you, that's great insight, I think I haven't articulated my words correctly in regard to having to rewrite "functions", just my ignorance! Cheers

Comment: I dont know if this makes any sense, but defining the sectors of a cartesian 3D space, you have 8 (x,y,z); (-x,y,z); (-x,-y,z); (-x,-y-z); (x, -y, z); (x, -y,-z); (x,y,-z); (-x,y,-z). In a tetrahedron you can define the sectors of space just as x,y; -x,y; -x,-y and x, -y. I have no idea what I'm saying, does it mean anything to any of you? :)